# Await stops execution of thread and never continues

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following:

```
public async Task<bool> SearchForUpdatesAsync()
{
    return await TaskEx.Run(() =>
    {
    if (!ConnectionChecker.IsConnectionAvailable())
        return false;

    // Check for SSL and ignore it
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return (true); };

    var configurations = UpdateConfiguration.Download(UpdateConfigurationFileUri, Proxy);
    var result = new UpdateResult(configurations, CurrentVersion,
        IncludeAlpha, IncludeBeta);

    if (!result.UpdatesFound)
        return false;

    _updateConfigurations = result.NewestConfigurations;
    double updatePackageSize = 0;
    foreach (var updateConfiguration in _updateConfigurations)
    {
        var newPackageSize = GetUpdatePackageSize(updateConfiguration.UpdatePackageUri);
        if (newPackageSize == null)
            throw new SizeCalculationException(_lp.PackageSizeCalculationExceptionText);

        updatePackageSize += newPackageSize.Value;
        _packageOperations.Add(new UpdateVersion(updateConfiguration.LiteralVersion),
            updateConfiguration.Operations);
    }

    TotalSize = updatePackageSize;
    return true;
});
}
```

As you can see I'm using **Microsoft.Bcl**. 
Now in my other class I wrote this code in a normal **void**:

```
TaskEx.Run(async delegate
{
    // ...
    _updateAvailable = await _updateManager.SearchForUpdatesAsync();
     MessageBox.Show("Test");
});
```

The problem I have is that it executes `_updateAvailable = await _updateManager.SearchForUpdatesAsync();` and then it doesn't continue the thread, it just stops as if there is nothing after that call. Visual Studio also tells me this after a while: `Thread ... exited with code 259`, so something seems to be still alive.

I debugged through it to search for any exceptions that could maybe be swallowed, but nothing, everything works fine and it executes the **return**-statement.
And that is what I don't understand, I never see the MessageBox and/or no code beyond this line's being executed.
After I talked to some friends, they confirmed that this shouldn't be. Did I make a horrible mistake when implementing async-await?

Thanks in advance, that's actually all I can say about that, I got no more information, I appreciate any tips and help as far as it's possible.

Comment: What is the point of the TaskEx?  Just await your method and you do not need to create another task that just calls the method synchronously again

Comment: @MatthewFrontino You mean the TaskEx.Run of the second code part above?

Comment: Yes, you have a method that awaits a task, that awaits a method.  Do you need that many layers?

Comment: @MatthewFrontino I think so, I can't await the method if there is no async-modifier, or should I write that modifier in front of the "void" to mark the whole method with that?
Or is there no need to await it at all? That's another point I haven't understood, yet, does that mean my async method already awaits the content when it runs the task inside it? That would mean I should change the type from "Task<bool>" to "bool", right?

Comment: Did you try calling the Result or using continue with methods

Comment: There are two possible problems. I can't know which one you have without seeing more of your code (like the void method in full). Possibility #1 The message box may not be able to be displayed from another thread. Possibility #2: You are building your Task correctly but not kicking it off correctly (by calling await, or less desirably .Wait())

Comment: I tried to do it with the "Result"-property but it results in the same, no execution of the code beyond although there isn't any await anymore.
@SilasReinagel As above, then it seems to be something different. It is not only the MessageBox btw, no code is ever executed there.
That's everything the method does right now.

Comment: Hmm, I think you have a bit of research to do.  `async` is a primitive way of using `Tasks`.  Basically they do the same thing, minus some details.  You mark a method as async and you expect to get a task which can be awaited.  When you are ready for the result of the method you await the task.  Microsoft has an e-learning academy platform that can teach you the basics of sync/await.

Comment: Why are you mixing Task & TaskEx?

Comment: Okay, I have made a lot of research, yet, also to understand the basics of async/await and so far it always made sense.

@JNYRanger TaskEx is the class provided by Microsoft.Bcl and that one includes Task.Run basically which returns a Task.

Comment: I understand that, but you shouldn't be mixing them if you're using .NET 4.5 or higher.  That was used to add backwards compatibility.

Comment: I use .NET 4.0, there is no other way except that if I want to use those methods.

Comment: Your issue is that you're experiencing deadlock.  Something isn't properly synchronized. We need more information to properly figure out where this is happening.

Comment: @JNYRanger Well, the call of await "await _updateManager.SearchForUpdatesAsync()" is basically done in the method "ShowUserInterface" in class "UpdaterUi" that's constructor takes a SynchronizationContext as a parameter. This method is called in a WindowsForm and actually that is everything. Before the call is executed it normally shows a SearchDialog by calling "Context.Post(searchDialog.ShowModalDialog, null);" and that's it. "Context" is the context provided (SynchronizationContext.Current).

But I left the away for now and it still doesn't work, that's why I did not mention it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73803/discussion-between-jnyranger-and-trade).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue that you're having is that you're unnecessarily wrapping your method in `TaskEx.Run()` and you are probably experiencing deadlock somewhere.

Your method signature is currently:

```
public async Task<bool> SearchForUpdatesAsync()
```

This means the following:

> **`async`** --> Doesn't actually do anything, but provides a "heads up" that `await` might be called within this method and that this method can be used as a runnable Task.
>   **`Task`** --> This method returns a runnable task that can be run asynchronously on the threadpool
>   **`<bool>`** --> This method actually returns bool when awaited.

The `await TaskEx.Run()` is unnecessarily since this says run this method and then don't return until after a value is available.  This is most likely causing a synchronization problem.  Removing this construct will make your method work properly, however you'll notice that now you have no reason to even include the `async` operator or the `Task<T>` portion since the method is actually synchronous anyway.  Usually you're only going to use `async` identifier on the method signature if you have methods that you are going to call `await` on them.

Instead you have two options.

1. Whenever you want to call `SearchForUpdates()` you can wrap this in a `Task<bool>.Run()` to run it asynchronously (or the Bcl equivalent)
2. Since you are using WinForms you might be better off using a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and just calling this method within it.

Regarding using the async-await pattern I think that this is a great article to use to make sure you're following best practices: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Yep, that worked and also that explanation helped me to understand it, now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to have async all the way through your layers, and then call **await** or less desirably **.Wait() / .Result** at the final use site.

Also, try to keep your UI calls separate from the backend work, since you can run into synchronicity/thread-context issue.

```
public class WinFormsCode
{
    private async Task WinsFormCodeBehindMethodAsync()
    {
        var updatesAvailable = await _updateManager.SearchForUpdatesAsync();
        MessageBox.Show("Updates Available: " + updatesAvailable.ToString());
    }

    private void WinsFormCodeBehindMethodSync()
    {
        var updatesAvailable = _updateManager.SearchForUpdatesAsync().Result;
        MessageBox.Show("Updates Available: " + updatesAvailable.ToString());
    }
}

public class UpdateManager
{
    public async Task<bool> SearchForUpdatesAsync()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how to properly use the async-await pattern.  If you go async, then you want to go async all the way.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Hm, I don't really understand that, if I await SearchForUpdatesAsync in SearchForUpdatesAsync, then this would result in an infinite loop, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JNYRanger: The chain of async must end at the UI call for some UI contexts/frameworks. While going full async is preferred all the way through, it is also acceptable to run synchronously at the presentation layer.

Comment: @Trade: You are calling "_updateManager.SearchForUpdatesAsync" which is presumably an external call. Should be no infinite loop, unless _updateManager is a reference to the class this method resides in.

Comment: The method is contained in the class that "_updateManager" is instantiated from. ;) As said, the call of "await _updateManager.SearchForUpdatesAsync()" was done in another class.

Comment: Not necessarily.  You can have methods within your ui that use async void if they are for event handlers.  However, you cannot update the UI asynchronously since that's running on the thread pool instead of the UI context.  Instead, you can use a callback on the UI context.

Comment: @SilasReinagel Your current code won't work, I can't return a single bool if the return type is actually Task<bool>.

Comment: @Trade You can if the method is `async`.  The code here is broken, but not for the reason you just gave.

Comment: @Trade: What do you mean you can't return a single bool as async Task<bool>? That's precisely what Task offers.

Comment: So, did that fix your problem? If so, please upvote the solution. If you have any more issues, just let me know.

Comment: @Silas Reinagel I will try it, just a moment.

Comment: @SilasReinagel Works, this is great! So I just removed the "TaskEx.Run" and there I go. Only one thing: The user can make it async again by putting the method inside "Task.Run" again, is that correct?

Comment: @Trade: I'm glad it's working for you. You are correct, any action can be run asynchonously by calling Task.Run.

Comment: @SilasReinagel okay, right, so the problem was that I basically double-wrapped it. Now this makes much more sense!

Comment: @Trade: Double-wrapping it wasn't the problem. The problem was the Task was not correctly begun, after it was created.